# How to merge two getjson response into one variable and then process that variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, getjson

I have getjson for page1 but I want to do same thing for page2 then process the sitecontent variable further. how I can make two getjson request one for page1 and one for page2? (I want to merge the two response in to one single variable.

```
<script> 

          $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.example.com/page1.php/&callback=?', function(data){

             var siteContents = data.contents; 

    //process sitecontent further

    });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must make first request, then in callback make second request.
Something like this:

```
var res;
$.getJSON(url1, function(data) {
    res = data.contents;
    $.getJSON(url2, function(data) {
        $.extend(res, data.contents);
    });
});
```